# Getting 'bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' in react/redux app

Tags: redux, react-redux

I'm trying to learn redux from Wes Bos's website:https://courses.wesbos.com/account and I'm trying to follow alog with his class. However, I'm getting an error even when following exactly what he has on the screen. I have 2 files - Main.js and reduxstagram.js. My Main.js is as follows:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { Link } from 'react-router';

    const Main = React.createClass({
      render(){
         return(
            <div>
             <h1>
                <Link to="/">Reduxstagram</Link>
            </h1>
           </div>
         )
        }
       })

     export default Main;
```

My reduxstagram.js is as follows:

```
    // let's go!
    import React from 'react';
    import { render } from 'react-dom';

     //import css
     import css from './styles/style.styl';

      //import components
      import Main from './components/Main';

      render(<Main/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

But when I try to render the page with 'npm start' I get following error:

```
     bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' in 
     react/redux app
```

The console gives the following errors:

```
     ERROR in ./components/Main.js
    Module parse failed: /Users/myUser/Downloads/Learn-Redux-Starter- 
     Files-master/learn-redux/components/Main.js Unexpected token 
       (7:12)
       You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
        SyntaxError: Unexpected token (7:12)
        at Parser.pp$4.raise (/Users/myUser/Downloads/Learn-Redux- 
          Starter-Files-master/learn- 


  redux/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2221:15)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/Users/myUser/Downloads/Learn-Redux- 
        Starter-Files-master/learn- 

  redux/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:603:10)
  at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (/Users/myUser/Downloads/Learn-Redux- 
       Starter-Files-master/learn- 

 redux/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1822:12)
     at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts 
   (/Users/myUser/Downloads/Learn-Redux-Starter-Files-master/learn- 
   redux/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1715:21)
     at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary 
     (/Users/myUser/Downloads/Learn-Redux-Starter-Files-master/learn- 

   redux/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1692:19)
        at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps 
      (/Users/myUser/Downloads/Learn-Redux-Starter-Files-master/learn- 


  redux/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1637:21)
      at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional 
   (/Users/myUser/Downloads/Learn-Redux-Starter-Files-master/learn- 
   redux/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1620:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (/Users/myUser/Downloads/Learn- 
    Redux-Starter-Files-master/learn- 
   redux/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1597:21)
  at Parser.pp$3.parseParenAndDistinguishExpression 
    (/Users/myUser/Downloads/Learn-Redux-Starter-Files-master/learn- 
   redux/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1861:32)
  at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (/Users/myUser/Downloads/Learn-Redux- 
   Starter-Files-master/learn- 

   redux/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1796:19)
   @ ./client/reduxstagram.js 13:12-41
```

Can someone point out what I'm missing?

Comment: Typically that means you're serving HTML where JS is expected, due to a fallback route or a proxy.

Comment: It seems that your loader cannot parse JSX. Did you add @babel/preset-react in your babel configuration?

Comment: I don't know about that specific component but I'm trying to learn react using Wes Bos' tutorial (link provided in OP); how do I check to see if @babel/preset-react is present in my babel configuration? (PS: I've never worked w/ Babel or react before)